# Scroll div using fadeIn

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code and what i am trying to do is when i click the button, content of div should be displayed from the initial of div.I am not good at js.For now when i click the button then div content doesnot shows untill i scroll the page . So how could i make it scroll automatically to the top of div content when i click the button?

//HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block" id="show"></button>

<div class="container-fluid" id="detail" style="display:none;"></div>
```

//Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#detail").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show").click(function() {
        $("#detail").fadeIn();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#detail").offset().top - 100
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an element above the div element.
After then, use this function in the button click event.

```
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
```

Here is the example.
https://plnkr.co/edit/kcs8UZaBcaegwTSSeThM?p=preview

Comment: Same answer had given by me please check my answer I have already given

Comment: Great. I didn't know about that. :) Keep in touch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ScrollTo plugin.

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
   //optionally remove the 500 (which is time in milliseconds) of the
   //scrolling animation to remove the animation and make it instant
   $.scrollTo($('#myDiv'), 500);
});
```